# Почему инициализацию полей прописывают вне тела конструктора

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор, инициализация

Практически всегда в в примерах кода встречал инициализацию полей класса вне тела конструктора:

```
MyClass(): a(1),b(2),c(3)
{ }
```

а не

```
MyClass()
{
 a = 1;
 b = 2;
 c = 3;
}
```

Если оба варианта рабочие, в чем практическая польза от инициализации вне тела конструктора?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В первом случае у вас вызываются конструкторы для полей, и тем самым осуществляется инициализация полей..

Во втором случае у вас сначала вызываются конструкторы по умолчанию, и, если инициализаторы полей отсутствуют в их определении, то затем еще вызываются копирующие операторы присваивания, чтобы инициализировать соответствующим образом эти поля, что может быть в конечном итоге очень затратно.

Представьте, например, что в конструкторе динамически выделяется память. Тогда затем в копирующем операторе присваивания эта память будет переопределяться.

Кроме того может так оказаться, что какой-то член данных вообще не имеет конструктора по умолчанию, а только конструкторы с параметрами. В этом случае второй вариант вообще не будет компилироваться.

Рассмотрите простой пример.

Данная программа будет успешно компилироваться

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int x;
    A( int x ) : x( x ) {}
};

struct B
{
    A a;
    B() : a( 10 ) {}
};

int main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```

Однако следующая программа компилироваться не будет

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int x;
    A( int x ) : x( x ) {}
};

struct B
{
    A a;
    B()
    {
        a = 10;
    }
};


int main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```

так как отсутствует конструктор по умолчанию у класса `A`, который должен быть вызван до передачи управления управления в тело конструктора `B`

Answer (score 4):

В порядке вызова.

Сначала поля класса инициализируется в списке инциализации (вариант 1). Если списка нет, то компилятор сделает его сам в том порядке, в котором поля объявлены в классе. Потом будет происходить то, что написано в теле конструктора (вариант 2).

Для конкретно вашего примера разницы никакой, т.к. у вас используются простые типы данных. Дополнительных накладных расходов нет.

Это имеет смысл для классов, которые в качестве полей имеют объекты других классов. Таким способом можно достичь *несоздание* объекта класса, если при инициализации какого-нибудь его поля произойдёт ошибка.
Ну и для объектов других классов могут быть затраты на инициализацию объекта. Поэтому может получиться повторный вызов.
Ну и последний аргумент - вариант 1 является хорошей практикой.

Думаю, что-то ещё добавят в комментариях и других ответах.